# File.delete() & File.renameTo() Not Working in Project Environment

Tags: java, file, project, delete-file, file-rename

I am trying to create an authentication system of sorts that uses a file called *Users.dat* to store user data. Currently, I am developing a method to remove users by **rewriting** the Users.dat file, omitting the user specified. The code below works in a basic environment with an all-encompassing directory containing the .java files and the *Users.dat* file in the same spot. The old *Users.dat* file is deleted and *Users.dat.tmp* is renamed to *User.dat*. (No problems here, everything works as intended).

```
public static boolean RemoveUser(String userName) {
        // TODO remove username from Users.dat
        try {

            File originalFile = new File("Users.dat");
            System.out.println(originalFile.getAbsolutePath());

            BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Users.dat"));

            String line = null;
            while ((line = read.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.indexOf(userName) != -1) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            String[] userInfo = line.split(", ");
            if (!userName.equals(userInfo[2])) {
                System.out.println("Username not found. No users removed.");
                read.close();
                return false;
            }
            File tempFile = new File(originalFile.getAbsolutePath() + ".tmp");
            PrintWriter print = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));
            String lineToRemove = line;

            BufferedReader read2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Users.dat"));
            while ((line = read2.readLine()) != null) {

                if (!line.trim().equals(lineToRemove)) {
                    print.println(line);
                    print.flush();
                }
            }
            print.close();
            read.close();
            read2.close();
            System.out.println(originalFile.getAbsolutePath());
            originalFile.delete(); //This line is not executing correctly
            tempFile.renameTo(originalFile); //Nor is this line

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Users.dat file format:

```
Joe, Last, jlast, 58c536ed8facc2c2a293a18a48e3e120, true
Sam, sone, samsone, 2c2a293a18a48e3e12058c536ed8facc, false
Jane, Best, jbest, 293a18a48e3e12052058c536ed8facc2c, false
Andrew, Estes, Aestes, 63a490d69aa544fd1272a976014ad570, true
Test, User, tuser, 63a490d69aa544fd1272a976014ad570, true
```

I have two System.out.println(originalFile.getAbsolutePath()) statements, one at the beginning, one at the end to make sure the path isn't getting screwed up in the process of everything somehow.

Like I said, the code works, however, when I try to implement it in my project, it creates the *Users.dat.tmp* and it writes the correct data to it, but it does not delete the old *Users.dat* file, nor does it rename the *Users.dat.tmp* file to replace *Users.dat*. I'm certain the directory is correct, as I am literally displaying it as the code executes. I can't figure out any other reason why originalFile.delete() and tempFile.renameTo(originalFile) aren't functioning properly.

**EDIT:**
Using java.nio.file, I was able to produce an error message. it reads:

```
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Path\Users.dat: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

I don't have the file open when this error message is shown, and I don't get this error using java.nio in my testing environment mentioned at the beginning. I'm not sure what other process the message is referring to.

**EDIT 2:**
I tried running the code on other machines, one a Mac, the other a Windows laptop, and the code functioned on the Mac just fine, but I was still seeing the same issue on the Windows laptop.

Comment: I assume you didn't get any exceptions?

Comment: As the [JavaDocs on File.delete()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#delete()) describe, this method does not throw any Exception -  it just returns `false`. "Note that the [Files](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html) class defines the [delete](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#delete(java.nio.file.Path)) method to throw an IOException when a file cannot be deleted. This is useful for error reporting and to diagnose why a file cannot be deleted."

Comment: So I recommend to try `java.nio.Files.delete(path)` instead, and see if you get a better (that is to say, any) error message.

Comment: I edited my post with the results from java.nio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the similar issue. My problem was not closing all the streams I read and written to the file. Thanks for your Edit #1, that was helpful
When you wrap
`BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Users.dat"));`
don't you need to close the inner readers too?
If not for the author, but for those who stambled upon this question (like me), hope this suggestion will be useful

Answer (score 0):

I had an earlier function that I was calling in main that was accessing Users.dat, but I never closed the BufferredReader in that function.